# Why doesn't jQuery UI hide element with hidden parent?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've been working on an one page app, and noticed that my dropdowns stays open sometimes when they suppose to be hidden. I investigated why that happens and find out that if parent element is hidden, hiding element with jQuery UI using extended `hide` functions is worthless.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drulia/BtwJJ/) example which shows what I mean, just try to click `Hide` & `Show` buttons, and then click `Show parent1` and try to hide element there. You'll notice that status indicator gets updated instantly but once you back to `parent2` you'll see the element is still visible.

I found that using jQuery `hide` without arguments or only with miliseconds passed, it does work correctly and stops working once I update it with jQuery UI arguments, so I assume it is jQuery UI not jQuery itself problem.

So my question is why jQuery UI is working in this way, is that the way it suppose to work or it is a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in jQuery UI, which got fixed in 1.10.2.

Here is a link to bug report ticket
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9120

Answer (score 0):

I think its the way its supposed to work. In this case when you go back to `parent2` on the line `$('#parent2').show();`, it by default shows all child elements too.. That is the `show()` is iterated on all elements inside `parent2`. Though this seems cumbersome, there is a way around it in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajo4you/BtwJJ/6/) which is a modified version of yours.

Comment: well it would make sense it to work in this way, but there is plenty of old bug reports about jQuery itself been working this way, which was fixed and now only jQuery UI works in this way, I think it is a bug, because there suppose to be same behaviour with functions which shares the same name. Your example in JSFiddle is quite complex for such a simple thing, I think simply calling a callback for `hide` function is much simpler way to workaround this issue. I already filled up bug report.

Comment: @giedrius i didn't use callback for `hide` because you had specified it with a delay. My method made it look like it worked all right.. There are alternate methods too working to this effect. And my method felt simple since i just added a flag to the effect to do the work. Cheers!!